# Unable to index dates in Elastic 2.3.1

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-mapping

My mapping:

```
{
    "field": {
        "dynamic_templates": [{
            "notanalyzed": {
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }],
        "properties": {
            "createdOn": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "lastUpdatedOn": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Classes:

```
package be.smartask.core.api.data;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Glenn Van Schil
 *         Created on 19/04/2016
 */
public class AbstractData {
    private final static SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private String id;
    private String createdOn;
    private String lastUpdatedOn;

    public AbstractData() {
    }

    public AbstractData(Date createdOn, String id, Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.createdOn = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(createdOn);
        this.id = id;
        this.lastUpdatedOn = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(lastUpdatedOn);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        try {
            return SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.parse(createdOn);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(createdOn);
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        try {
            return SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.parse(lastUpdatedOn);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.lastUpdatedOn = SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(lastUpdatedOn);
    }
}
```

And

```
package be.smartask.data;

import be.smartask.core.api.data.AbstractData;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Glenn Van Schil
 *         Created on 25/01/2016
 */
public class Field extends AbstractData {

    private String name;
    private FieldType fieldType;
    private String unit;
    private String userId;
    private String projectId;

    public Field() {
    }

    public Field(Date createdOn, String id, Date lastUpdatedOn, FieldType fieldType, String name, String projectId, String unit, String userId) {
        super(createdOn, id, lastUpdatedOn);
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
        this.name = name;
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public FieldType getFieldType() {
        return fieldType;
    }

    public void setFieldType(FieldType fieldType) {
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

and when I try to index it I get the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1461223048000" is malformed at "8000"

When I remove the format from my mapping it takes **strict_date_optional_time || epoch_millis** by default for the format, but I don't want that.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve it?

## Update 1

When I change my mapping to:

```
{
    "field": {
        "dynamic_templates": [{
            "notanalyzed": {
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }],
        "properties": {
            "createdOn": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_hour_minute_second || epoch_millis"
            },
            "lastUpdatedOn": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_hour_minute_second || epoch_millis"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Class to:

```
package be.smartask.core.api.data;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Glenn Van Schil
 *         Created on 19/04/2016
 */
public class AbstractData {
    private String id;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;

    public AbstractData() {
    }

    public AbstractData(Date createdOn, String id, Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.id = id;
        this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        return lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }
}
```

It works, but I still prefer to do it without the **|| epoch_millis**. Is there a way to get rid of it?